# Eclipse, Java: Generate class field from static string or vice versa

Tags: java, eclipse, pojo

I am working on a JAVA web service with mongo, In order to implement mongo java driver POJO api (like Morphia), I establish my POJO like the following:

```
    public class User {
        public static final String USER_NAME = "userName";
        private String userName;
        public User() {
        }
        // getter && setter //
    }
```

`USER_NAME = "userName"` is a reference for future use as a filed name. What I'm trying to achieve is that I could use a simple `if` to check if received data equals to the field name. For example :

```
    User user = new User();
    String receivedData = httpRequest.getParameter(User.USER_NAME);
    if (receivedData == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        user.setUserName(receivedData);
        userCollection.insertOne(user);  
            // userCollection is MongoCollection<User>
        return Gson().toJson(user);
    }
```

I am looking for a eclipse function or plug in that could auto generate one of the declaration (`USER_NAME = "userName"` and `private String userName`) by the other and make sure the consistency of the code.

Of course, that would be appreciated if there's any suggestion for a better practice.

**EDIT**

Stephan's reflection approach gives a great flexibility for the code. However, compare to my original simplified example, the real situation might be more complex. For example, one httpRequest has many different parameters which are stored in different(n) POJO and each POJO has many different(n) fields. In that case, we will do n*n loop for just getting the field value.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Can you give some examples?

Comment: You can reference the field `userName` only from within the class (its `private`) and also not from a `static` context. But you can provide a **getter** method. The static field can be accessed from anywhere by `User.USER_NAME`. So your class can of course use the static value as own name: `this.userName = User.USER_NAME`.

Comment: I've edited the post. Thanks

Comment: As mentioned, this is for mongo java driver POJO api use. In this api, the java class field name would also be used as the mongo document field name.

Comment: What do you mean by _auto generate_? Generate source code (`*.java`) or byte code (`*.class`)? Note, the Java compiler inlines constants (e. g. in your example every use of `User.USER_NAME` is compiled as `"userName"`). So if you change the value of a constant, you have recompile all Java classes where the constant is referenced.

Comment: What I am looking for is something like getter/setter generator in eclipse. Or a better practice for this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the same for all fields of the POJO, consider iterating the result of `User.class.getFields()`. For each `Field` get the name (`f.getName()`), use the name to retrieve the value and set it to the field (`f.set(object,value)`). With this approach there's no need for a constant like `USER_NAME`.

**EDIT 1**: If performance is an issue you may of course collect all those fields into some collection up-front once and for all, but then the bottleneck will remain at having to try `httpRequest.getParameter()` for each possible field. Nothing specific to the reflective approach.

**EDIT 2**: In a "nicer" language there could be type checked syntax for retrieving a `Field` instance, e.g., imagine (not Java):

```
Field f = User::userName;
```

This answer basically demonstrates that generating redundant constants is not strictly necessary, since the thing that consistently connects the name to the field already exists, it's a `Field`.

Comment: Thanks for a different approach, please also see my edit